# How to make subsequent PDE product builds not rebuild dependent plugins

Tags: ant, build, build-process, build-automation, eclipse-pde

Our build process constructs several products out of a relatively small set of plugins. To trigger the build, we have an Ant file that just iterates through the names of the products, like so:

```
    <for list="all,client1,client1_64,client2,client2_64,rob" param="feature">
        <sequential>
            <java jar="${eclipse.launcher}" fork="true" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="-application" />
                <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner" />
                <arg value="-buildfile" />
                <arg value="${eclipse.pde.build}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml" />
                <arg value="-DbaseLocation=${eclipse.dir}" />
                <arg value="-Dproduct=${feature.dir}/@{feature}/my.product" />
                <arg value="-DbuildLabel=@{feature}-${build.timestamp}" />
                <arg value="-DbuildId=My_@{feature}_${release.name}-${build.timestamp}" />
                <arg value="-Dtimestamp=${release.name}-${build.timestamp}" />
                <arg value="-DbuildDirectory=${build.dir}" />
            </java>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

Not surprisingly perhaps, the 'all' product includes every one of our plugins, the others some subset. My problem is that each iteration through this loop recompiles and packages every plugin, throwing out work that was done previously. Not a big deal at a couple of products, but now most of our build time is spent recompiling and packaging plugins.

Can someone point me to a better way of making the build process build plugins only once as all these products are packaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "all" product includes everything, I would suggest breaking it out separate from the other products.

Once the "all" product is built, you can take the output of that and make it available to the other product builds.  If your "all" product build is producing p2 metadata, you can use [repoBaseLocation and transformedRepoLocation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_p2_productbuilds.htm), otherwise you can use `pluginPath`.

For the subsequent product builds, use a new empty `buildDirectory` so that they don't see the source for the bundles, only the binary output from the "all" product.  If everything these products need is available in binary form, then no compilation will be necessary and these builds essentially become packaging operations.

Comment: That sounds promising.  It's going to be a bit before I get a chance to try it, but will let you know.

Comment: Looks like this is right.  One follow up though.  Each of those products contains a single feature, which has all of the required plugins.  My understanding is that to use p2 in the way you describe, I would have to create features for each plugin, and then have the products include sets of features.  Does that sound right to you?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `pluginPath` to work, so what I did was to copy the already-built plugins into the "dropins" folder of the Eclipse target. PDE picks them up automatically and doesn't rebuild them.